# How do i write IF-ELSE Statement in Java

Tags: java, excel, eclipse, if-statement, talend

We are trying to write calculated field as ship date  if-then-else statement into java with an eclipse (Talend DI TOOL)

Environment :
we are trying to create job in  talend.

```
source systems (sql server and excel file)---->tmap---->Target system(Excel file)
```

Input Expression : if-then-else formula

**ship date**

```
if ([Customer])='0000001' or 
(TRIM([Corp Acct Name]))='GENERAL' or (TRIM([Corp Acct Name]))='ABC' or (TRIM([Corp Acct Name]))='XYZ'
or (TRIM([Corp Acct Name]))='CDE' then ([ShipDate]) 
elseif DATEPART('weekday',([MABD])) =1 and [Total Lead Time]<=5 then (([MABD])-[Total Lead Time]-2)
elseif DATEPART('weekday',([MABD])) =1 and [Total Lead Time]>5 then (([MABD])-[Total Lead Time]-4)
elseif DATEPART('weekday',([MABD])) =2 and [Total Lead Time]<=1 then (([MABD])-[Total Lead Time])
elseif DATEPART('weekday',([MABD])) =2 and [Total Lead Time]<=6 then (([MABD])-[Total Lead Time]-2)
elseif DATEPART('weekday',([MABD])) =2 and [Total Lead Time]>6 then (([MABD])-[Total Lead Time]-4)
elseif DATEPART('weekday',([MABD])) =3 and [Total Lead Time]<=2 then (([MABD])-[Total Lead Time])
elseif DATEPART('weekday',([MABD])) =3 and [Total Lead Time]<=7 then (([MABD])-[Total Lead Time]-2)
elseif DATEPART('weekday',([MABD])) =3 and [Total Lead Time]>7 then (([MABD])-[Total Lead Time]-4)
elseif DATEPART('weekday',([MABD])) =4 and [Total Lead Time]<=3 then (([MABD])-[Total Lead Time])
elseif DATEPART('weekday',([MABD])) =4 and [Total Lead Time]<=8 then (([MABD])-[Total Lead Time]-2)
elseif DATEPART('weekday',([MABD])) =4 and [Total Lead Time]>8 then (([MABD])-[Total Lead Time]-4)
elseif DATEPART('weekday',([MABD])) =5 and [Total Lead Time]<=4 then (([MABD])-[Total Lead Time])
elseif DATEPART('weekday',([MABD])) =5 and [Total Lead Time]<=9 then (([MABD])-[Total Lead Time]-2)
elseif DATEPART('weekday',([MABD])) =5 and [Total Lead Time]>9 then (([MABD])-[Total Lead Time]-4)
elseif DATEPART('weekday',([MABD])) =6 and [Total Lead Time]<=4 then (([MABD])-[Total Lead Time]-1)
elseif DATEPART('weekday',([MABD])) =6 and [Total Lead Time]<=9 then (([MABD])-[Total Lead Time]-3)
elseif DATEPART('weekday',([MABD])) =6 and [Total Lead Time]>9 then (([MABD])-[Total Lead Time]-5)
elseif DATEPART('weekday',([MABD])) =7 and [Total Lead Time]<=4 then (([MABD])-[Total Lead Time]-2)
elseif DATEPART('weekday',([MABD])) =7 and [Total Lead Time]<=9 then (([MABD])-[Total Lead Time]-4)
elseif DATEPART('weekday',([MABD])) =7 and [Total Lead Time]>9 then (([MABD])-[Total Lead Time]-6)
END
```

We tried :Ternery operator in talend

```
row1.customer='0000001'|| trim(row1.CorpAcctName)='GENERAL'|| trim(row1.CorpAcctName)='ABC' or trim(row1.CorpAcctName)='XYZ or trim(row1.CorpAcctName)=='SCDE' ||?row1.ShipDate:
Integer.toString (TalendDate.getPartOfDate("DAY_OF_WEEK",row1.MABD)=1)-1) and row2.L+1<5?row1.MABD-row2.L+1-2:
Integer.toString (TalendDate.getPartOfDate("DAY_OF_WEEK",row1.MABD=1)-1) and row2.L+1>5?row1.MABD-row2.L+1-4:
Integer.toString (TalendDate.getPartOfDate("DAY_OF_WEEK",row1.MABD=2)-1) and row2.L+1<=1?row1.MABD-row2.L+1:
Integer.toString (TalendDate.getPartOfDate("DAY_OF_WEEK",row1.MABD=2)-1) and row2.L+1<=6?row1.MABD-row2.L+1-2:
Integer.toString (TalendDate.getPartOfDate("DAY_OF_WEEK",row1.MABD=2)-1) and row2.L+1>6?row1.MABD-row2.L+1-4:
Integer.toString (TalendDate.getPartOfDate("DAY_OF_WEEK",row1.MABD=3)-1) and row2.L+1<=2?row1.MABD-row2.L+1:
Integer.toString (TalendDate.getPartOfDate("DAY_OF_WEEK",row1.MABD=3)-1) and row2.L+1<=7?row1.MABD-row2.L+1-2:
Integer.toString (TalendDate.getPartOfDate("DAY_OF_WEEK",row1.MABD=3)-1) and row2.L+1>7?row1.MABD-row2.L+1-4:
Integer.toString (TalendDate.getPartOfDate("DAY_OF_WEEK",row1.MABD=4)-1) and row2.L+1<=3?row1.MABD-row2.L+1:
Integer.toString (TalendDate.getPartOfDate("DAY_OF_WEEK",row1.MABD=4)-1) and row2.L+1<=8?row1.MABD-row2.L+1-2:
Integer.toString (TalendDate.getPartOfDate("DAY_OF_WEEK",row1.MABD=4)-1) and row2.L+1>8?row1.MABD-row2.L+1-4:
Integer.toString (TalendDate.getPartOfDate("DAY_OF_WEEK",row1.MABD=5)-1) and row2.L+1<=4?row1.MABD-row2.L+1:
Integer.toString (TalendDate.getPartOfDate("DAY_OF_WEEK",row1.MABD=5)-1) and row2.L+1<=9?row1.MABD-row2.L+1-2:
Integer.toString (TalendDate.getPartOfDate("DAY_OF_WEEK",row1.MABD=5)-1) and row2.L+1>9?row1.MABD-row2.L+1-4:
Integer.toString (TalendDate.getPartOfDate("DAY_OF_WEEK",row1.MABD=6)-1) and row2.L+1<=4?row1.MABD-row2.L+1-1:
Integer.toString (TalendDate.getPartOfDate("DAY_OF_WEEK",row1.MABD=6)-1) and row2.L+1<=9?row1.MABD-row2.L+1-3:
Integer.toString (TalendDate.getPartOfDate("DAY_OF_WEEK",row1.MABD=6)-1) and row2.L+1>9?row1.MABD-row2.L+1-5:
Integer.toString (TalendDate.getPartOfDate("DAY_OF_WEEK",row1.MABD=7)-1) and row2.L+1<=4?row1.MABD-row2.L+1-2:
Integer.toString (TalendDate.getPartOfDate("DAY_OF_WEEK",row1.MABD=7)-1) and row2.L+1<=9?row1.MABD-row2.L+1-4:
Integer.toString (TalendDate.getPartOfDate("DAY_OF_WEEK",row1.MABD=7)-1) and row2.L+1>9?row1.MABD-row2.L+1-6:""
```

Any help on it would be much appreciated ?

Comment: `if-else` is not an expression, it is a statement. Java has no "routines", what you mean is most probably a method. I would recommend a starter tutorial like [this one](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/index.html).

Answer (score 1):

first you have multiple syntax errors in your expression : if you want to compare 2 Int, the correct operator is "==".
(And If you want to compare two String, you should use `"0000001".equals(row1.customer)`).

This expression doesn't make sense :

```
 Integer.toString (TalendDate.getPartOfDate("DAY_OF_WEEK",row1.MABD=1)-1)
```

if you want to compare DAY_OF_WEEK to 1, use

```
(TalendDate.getPartOfDate("DAY_OF_WEEK",row1.MABD)-1) ==1
```

Then, using raw Ternary operator in a tMap is perhaps not the best thing to do : it is not really fit for a complex expression like this one (no comments available, no possible reusing). You should instead create a method in the "Routine" section, and give it row1.customer,row1.CorpAcctName,row1.ShipDate,row1.MABD as parameters.
In this routine method , you could then use IF/ELSE operators, something that you can't use in tMap directly.

```
  public static int myFunction(String customer,String CorpAcctName,Integer ShipDate,Integer MABD) {
//adding comment is possible here
            if ("0000001".equals(customer).......) {
```

Then in tMap, you just have to call your function in the expression constructor.

Comment: is that possible to give try  Adding one elseif line in  your public function .  it will be really helpful for me .

Comment: I tried public function with one else if  BUT Getting error on execution of routine  as per your direction  here is link http://paste.ofcode.org/QeCgHQuawvJpHAsC2Pg76H

Comment: Error message says that setTime(Date) in the type Calendar is not applicable for the arguments (String) : you should use a Date type for param MABD in order to get TalendDate.getPartofDate() working

Comment: After supplying Date in MABD getting following error http://paste.ofcode.org/hGrGYMxaCgvCMiVh6yBgUH

Comment: are you actually reading the error message before posting it ? you used java.sql.Date instead of a java.util.Date type in the method.

Comment: Yes ,i am  invastigating  first on google.But  trying to use in talend routine.

Comment: EVEN iF i am giving   the Date for MABD . getting this : The method setTime(Date) in the type Calendar is not applicable for the arguments (String)